# Graphic on Surface of Mesh

Tags: uv

I am relatively n00b to mapping so apologize if this is an easy one.
I have this mesh imported as an FBX from a program called Marvelous Designer.
It is a t shirt and on it is a graphic.

For some reason, when I apply a sculpt tool (smooth) the graphic gets "erased".
Here's a screenshot of what the mesh looks like in Sculpt mode: the gray box signifies the area where the graphic is when switched to Material view.

Can anyone explain what kind of UV mapping this and how I can smooth this mesh without affecting the graphic? I do not understand how it is situated or where it is located when I open the UV map of the mesh?

[image]

Comment: The sculpt tool is changing your UV Map, so the mapping gets lost.  You should do all of the sculpting and then create the UV Map.  Alternatively, enable images as planes add-on, import your graphic as an image plane as a separate object and shrink wrap it to the mesh.

Comment: @MartyFouts this will be my first time experimenting with the shrinkwrap modifier. What combination would you recommend? Been fiddling with it for a short while and I can't seem to get the plane to react to the contours of the mesh

Comment: First, edit the plane and subdivide it several times.  It has to have geometry to bend in order for the shrinkwrap to work.  Then I'd try Project and On Surface first and then just work my way through the options until i found one that works.

Comment: @MartyFouts Having some difficulty,  I added a ton of subdivisions to the plane but the result is still this strange pixelated mess. Is there any alternative?

Comment: can you add your blend file to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: @MartyFouts Check this out [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=m7ov8O5a" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/m7ov8O5a/)

Comment: @MartyFouts In the past I'd create a material that has both the fabric pattern as well as the shirt design combined together. However, seeing how I had to combine all of the pieces of the shirt (sleeves, collar, etc.) into one mesh in order to smooth it, that approach no longer works